# How to hide data received via HTTP requests?

Tags: angularjs, rest, security, http

I am currently designing a web application using AngularJS. In this I am fetching and posting data via Rest API(s) with different methods. The data I retrieving is fetched in the form of JSON.

**Problem:**
Issue here is, while I am using **https**, the data sent and received via HTTP requests can still be seen in proxy tool or traffic monitors. All the JSON can be easily read from this.
Each of my request has a **token** attached in it's header which takes care of authentication. However, once authorized, there is some part I don't want to be displayed in/ caught in such monitoring tools.

**Question:**
This data is stored in an encrypted way in database and all, however while coming via HTTP request, it is first decrypted and then sent. How can I hide/protect this data?

Answer (score 5):

You can't.

If you give it to the client, then the client has to be able to see it.

If the user has configured their browser to proxy requests, then the proxy is the client.

Once the data leaves your server in an HTTP response then anyone/anything thing the user of the client wants to trust with that data can access it. You don't have control at that point.

Comment: So basically the only way to protect this data is to keep it in encrypted format and then decrypt it on my Angular side once it reaches the client?

Comment: That won't stop the monitoring tools built into the browser (e.g. the JavaScript debugger) from examining it.

Comment: So basically there is **no way** no protect the data?

Comment: Correct. You can't give the data to the user without giving it to the user.

Comment: "You can't give the data to the user without giving it to the user." Perfect logic :D

Answer (score 0):

proxy tool or traffic monitors **will see https data only if the client has accepted** the man-in-the-middle (MITM) by installing the ssl certificate used by the MITM:

To see the content (other than the host name) of an https connection, someone who is neither the client or the server must do a MITM.

If someone do a MITM with a certificate not trusted by the client, the client will reject the connection.

WARNING: If the server do NOT use HSTS, the person doing the MITM can do an SSLSTRIP attack if the first connection is http. In that case, the MITM do not need a trusted certificate because the connection will stay in plain text (http)

Comment: Can you kindly elaborate a bit? Or share a link to understand the same?

Comment: @ashhem I've add some explanations, could you tell me which points are still unclear?